# Header file works fine in one #include, causes syntax errors in another

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, header-files

I've got a legacy header file in my C++ project that is known to be fine. It's worked in various places in the code base without issues.

It does drag in a lot of other headers with it, which I think might be part of the issue:

```
/* legacy.h: */

#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

// (Some definitions I need)


/* A.h: */

#include "C.h" // The rabbit hole continues for another few layers


/* B.h */

#include <windows.h>
#include "D.h" // Again, this also pulls in more things
```

I've written a new module in this project that has also worked fine for weeks:

```
/* module.h */

// Status codes for new module
struct Status {
    enum Enum           
    {
        ALL_GOOD = 0,
        ERROR
    };
};


/* module.cpp */

#include "module.h"

// (Code that previously didn't require the legacy header)
```

Today, I made a relatively small addition that required pulling in the legacy header.

All of the sudden, nothing compiles! I get hundreds of confusing syntax errors such as:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before 'constant'

Weirdly, these errors will start on different lines in either module.h or module.cpp depending on the order I try to use the headers.

The worst part is, the problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with my new code in module.cpp. Heck, I even reverted back to the version that had been working for weeks. That still works, but the second I include legacy.h, everything breaks!

What's going on here? **Both my module and this header are known to work just fine elsewhere, so how could they possibly cause *syntax* errors when brought together?**

Comment: What is the error? BTW, don't ever assume any code to be *"known to be fine"* just because it "worked" for years without problems.

Comment: Could the downvoters please explain? I opened the question because one like this would have saved me a full work day had it existed when I ran in to the problem. The symptoms were mystifying, but the root cause was simple and made me feel foolish. I've deliberately tried to couch it in the terms I was searching for while having the issue, but I'd love to improve it to be more generally useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be a victim of a preprocessor macro somewhere in the include chain of legacy.h. I'd bet the syntax errors originate on the first use of Status::ERROR as mentioned in your header:

```
/* module.h */

// Status codes for new module
struct Status {
    enum Enum           
    {
        ALL_GOOD = 0,
        ERROR // <- Syntax errors appear here
    };
};
```

In this case, the offender is probably

```
/* B.h */

#include <windows.h>
```

I think windows.h has a macro called ERROR.

Consider using a different naming scheme than all caps for your enum definitions, as programmers #defining a macro will often choose such names.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case, with the compiler for example not understanding a templated class use:

```cpp
        class SGMarkupElement: public std::enable_shared_from_this<SGMarkupElement> {
```

with gcc throwing a syntax error on the opening `<`, but only when including the header containing the line from a test executable - from the corresponding library implementation file, it compiled fine. Turns out, in the implementation file I was including the `memory` header but not in the test ! Adding that in the header file fixed all the syntax errors.